# Drupal gallery in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, drupal, plugins, slider, gallery

I have been asked to advise on a gallery on their [Old site](http://www.graemeborchers.com/photo/D%C3%A9cor/D%C3%A9cor_01) and recreate it in WordPress. I dont know what gallery plugin they used, but do you know where I can find a tutorial or another plugin that looks identical to it? Any suggestions will help.

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 0):

Yup Sure You can search a gallery plugin at the site [Wordpress plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/random-image-gallery-with-pretty-photo-zoom/) here is one plugin as per you need fro your site.

Answer (score 0):

This site has some handmade effects. I uses the [Fisheye](http://www.graemeborchers.com/sites/all/themes/fourseasons/interface.js) plugin and the [jQuery Lightbox](https://drupal.org/project/jlightbox) module ubt it also use them manually. If you inspect the source of the page you will find out the functionality.